# Why do the arrays I'm creating within my loop not contain all the values I've added after the loop completes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in Java Script that I'm trying to split into two arrays using a test within a loop. The console is logging that the two objects are being stored, but after the loop finishes the `inhaledArray` array only contains one object.

```
for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) 
         {
            var inhaledArray = new Array();
            var otherArray = new Array();

            if(results[i].get('MedicationType') == "inhaled")
            {
                //inhaledArray is dumping results
                console.log(results[i]);
                inhaledArray.push(results[i]);
            }
            if(results[i].get('MedicationType') == "other")
            {
                otherArray.push(results[i]);
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *resetting* the output at every iteration (by pointing the variable to a new array).

Move the array setup code outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Alex already answered your question, but here's a suggestion. If you ever have a bunch of arrays that store basically the same data, consider using an object instead:

```
var categories = {};

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var name = results[i].get('MedicationType');

    if (name in categories) {
        categories[name].push(results[i]);
    } else {
        categories[name] = [results[i]];
    }
}

console.log(categories.inhaled);
console.log(categories.other);
```

That way, you can account for all of the category types without hard-coding anything.

Comment: This is a better alternative. However, better hope `"hasOwnProperty"` is never a medication type (or `categories = Object.create(null);`). ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are initializing the array inside the forloop, just move the Array initialization before the for loop like below

```
var inhaledArray = new Array();
var otherArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (results[i].get('MedicationType') == "inhaled") {
        //inhaledArray is dumping results
        console.log(results[i]);
        inhaledArray.push(results[i]);
    }
    if (results[i].get('MedicationType') == "other") {
        otherArray.push(results[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would cache `results[i].get('MedicationType')` and change your second `if` into an `else if`.

Comment: I just moved the init. over the forloop, I didn't change anything else.. He might get confused

Comment: @alaasdk Confusion is necessary sometimes if it leads to better code.